# LED strip gets dimmed down after a while

Tags: led

I have a 5630 LED strip ~3.5 length  powered by a 12V 1A wall PSU. After 30 min of operation the  PSU gets very hot and the light gets dimmed down a bit. I assume that 1Ampere is not enough but I am a newbie to electronics so I am not sure at all.

If the ampere is low how can I calculate it and find the ideal amount?
I appreciate your help

Comment: Lets see, we have an unknown amount of unknown parts (LEDs) that are wired in an unknown way, powered by an unknown device...

Comment: How much current is your LED strip supposed to draw?

Comment: The 5630 is the LED chip itself, but strips using this LED are made in different ways. Some strips are designed to work from 12V, some work from 24V. Some strips have 30 LEDs per meter, some have 60. They all have different power requirements. You need to either (a) go back to the seller and ask them what power supply you need, or (b) get the datasheet of the LED strip and work out the power requirements.

Comment: I quick Google tells me that a typical 3m strip using 5630 LEDs consumes 72W at 12V, that is 6A. But you should not rely on this figure, your strip may be different.

Comment: The "amperage" works a bit differently than you expect. It is ok if you have a 12V 2A or a 12V 5A or a 12V 10A  power supply - assuming that the amperage of the power supply is bigger than the amperage what the led strip draws. You can not hurt the led strip if you run it from a stronger power supply, e.g. 12V 10A. (But you will hirt the led strip if you run it from a higher voltage.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to approach your problem.

The first is to determine what the circuit being powered is. This means getting a data sheet for the parts involved (ALL of them), then figuring out how the components are connected, and from there determining what the power requirements are.

The second approach ignores the theoretical details, and starts with a strip containing a single LED (or 3 LEDs for an RGB strip). This single LED is turned on, and current measured. The length of the complete strip is then divided by the length of a single LED, and the ratio multiplied by the single LED current.

The second approach requires that you get yourself a cheap DMM (digital multimeter), and learn how to use it. If you're going to build anything electrical or electronic, you need to do this anyways - it's the most basic tool you need. If you don't have one and aren't willing to spend the 5 bucks or so needed for a super cheapo (although 20 for a just cheap one is a better idea), just give up on building stuff. You will be flying blind and will never be able to figure out what is wrong with a circuit, let alone how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

5630 leds are typically 50 mA at 3.3 recommended max forward voltage. 1 meter, 3.3 feet of 5630 led strip typically have 72 leds, in 3 led segments.

72 leds / 3 led per segment = 24 segments * 0.05 Amps = 1.2 Amps.

You are over driving the power supply.

Typically, Diodes will drop their forward voltage, increasing their current draw, when over heated. Most 5630 led strips run a bit hot unless on a heatsink like an aluminum bar. So that 1.2 Amps increases after a while.

At that point, the power supply is over loaded by much more than 1 Amp, so if it has current limiting, it will trigger.

***Your power supply is too small for 1 meter of 5630 leds. Use a ammeter to measure the current drawn to confirm.*** Typically, you want your current draw to be 80% ~ 90% of the rated current of the Power Supply used. Go with 1.5 to 2 Amp supply for best results.

**If you are driving 3.6 Meters not feet, multiply all these numbers by 3.6...**